# How to logout properly when using BotAuth

Tags: c#, botframework

While using [BotAuth](https://github.com/richdizz/BotAuth), what is the right way to logout existing logged-in user? In [AuthBot](https://github.com/matvelloso/AuthBot), it was done using `await context.Logout();`.

On going through BotAuth [code](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth/blob/master/CSharp/BotAuth.AADv1/ADALAuthProvider.cs#L76), I find the following code doing the logout but it's not been shown in any Samples.

```
public async Task Logout(AuthenticationOptions authOptions, IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.UserData.RemoveValue($"{this.Name}{ContextConstants.AuthResultKey}");
        context.UserData.RemoveValue($"{this.Name}{ContextConstants.MagicNumberKey}");
        context.UserData.RemoveValue($"{this.Name}{ContextConstants.MagicNumberValidated}");
        string signoutURl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=" + System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(authOptions.RedirectUrl);
        await context.PostAsync($"In order to finish the sign out, please click at this [link]({signoutURl}).");
    }
```

On calling the above function, I get the following error though the userdata is cleared :
[image]
Is this the right way to logout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find that the return URL will be `http://localhost:3979/Callback` (without any querystring) after I did Logout operation, in [the source code of botauth](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth/blob/9a0a9f1b665f4aa95b6d60d09346dda90d8b314e/CSharp/BotAuth/Controllers/CallbackController.cs), I find that it directly returns exception with **BadRequest** status:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Callback")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Callback()
{
    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new Exception());
}
```

I do a test to modify this `Callback` with the following code, it works as expected on my side.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Callback")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Callback()
{
    //return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new Exception());

    var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    resp.Content = new StringContent("<html><body>Logout success</body></html>", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, @"text/html");
    return resp;
}
```

***Test Result:***

[image]